# How to get number of comparisons in 3 merge sort?

Tags: mergesort, recurrence

How to get number of comparisons in 3 merge sort with equal or not equal sub parts using masters theorem.

I got 3l(n/3)+3n as the recurrence relation and if I apply master theorem I get O(log n).Is this right way to go about this question

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not a computer programming question. It is about algorithmic analysis.

Comment: The number of moves is n · ⌈log3(n)⌉. During a 3 way merge, there are 2 compares (to determine smallest value of 3) for each move, so worst case is  ~ 2 · n · ⌈log3(n)⌉. Best case (such as already sorted data) is ~ (2/3 + 1/3 + 0) n · ⌈log3(n)⌉ = ~ n · ⌈log3(n)⌉ .